# How to transform cMessage to cPacket in OMNeT++?

Tags: omnet++

I need help to transform a cMessage to MsgData which is of type cPacket.

My MsgData is my message that I created:

```
packet MsgData {
     string origem;
    int cont;
    double payload;
    double timestamp;
}
```

I used the function static_cast but it doesn't work. I tried to use dynamic_cast and doesn't work too.

My code:

```
void UdpTrafficRedirect::retransmitDataMessage(cMessage *msg) {
     ASSERT(check_and_cast<MsgData *>(msg));
     MsgData *trafficMsg = static_cast<MsgData *>(msg);
}
```

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work" - does not compile or there is a runtime error or does not recognize your message? Could you provide some logs or output of your code?

Comment: when the first data is sent, the simulation stop and the window is automatically closed whit error message: "simulation has encountered a problema" and in error details: "finished with error". Just this!

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use directly check_cast<>(), if your packet is not one of the expected type, it will generate an error, as with ASSERT.

```
void UdpTrafficRedirect::retransmitDataMessage(cMessage *msg) {
     MsgData *trafficMsg = check_and_cast<MsgData *>(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ASSERT` is not necessary because `check_and_cast` actually does the same. However, I suggest additional checking using `dynamic_cast`.

```
void UdpTrafficRedirect::retransmitDataMessage(cMessage *msg) {
    if (dynamic_cast<MsgData *>(msg)) {
        MsgData  * trafficMsg = check_and_cast<MsgData *>(msg);
        int a = trafficMsg->getCont();
    } else {
        EV << "Message " << msg << " is not a MsgData packet" << endl;
        // other checking of msg
    }
}
```